# How do I display quotes in plain text email after being sanitized in php?

Tags: php, swiftmailer, sanitization

I have a form that submits name, email, and a message to another person that gets sent out as mail using SwiftMailer.

First, I sanitize:

```
$_POST['message'] = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Then I initialize SwiftMailer setting the Content Type to plain text..

```
->setContentType('text/plain')
```

..and then set the body with the message..

```
->setBody(htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['message']))
```

Originally, I didn't have the htmlspecialchars_decode in there, but in the plain text email that gets delivered quotes appear with the `&#39;` code. I've tried `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlspecialchars_decode` but can't seem to figure out what will make the quote display properly in a plain text email after being sanitized.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but some help would greatly be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Before testing with any of the $_POST variables, go ahead and try something like this first:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

// Give the message a subject
->setSubject('Your subject')

// Set the From address with an associative array
->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))

// Set the To addresses with an associative array
->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))

// And optionally an alternative body
->setBody("It's best to test", "text/plain");
```

Once you get it down without using any posted variables, test in a page with something like the following:

```
<?php 
$variable = "It's good to test";
//do any of your cleaning here
echo $variable;
?>
```

Once you get both working, then combine it.

Remember, there are plenty of libraries out there that will help you with cleaning your code.